# Read request body with Akka-Http and send each line to the message queue on an Actor

Tags: akka-stream, akka-http

I'm googling for an example that could fit my use case, but I haven't found any so far.

I'm writing an Akka WebService that should process a potentially huge plain text request body sending each line to an Actor's incoming message queue.

Could any of you write some code here or just head me to an example page?

I actually have no idea from where to start: the big problem to me is dealing with streams in general (in my case I want to use Akka streaming library)

Comment: Please define "huge".  Is the request too big to hold in memory all at once?

Comment: Not that huge, actually... you made me realize the file size can be controlled by the sender, so it could be sent in chunks in case it is a huge one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the request body you can use the [`extractRequestEntity`](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/routing-dsl/directives/basic-directives/extractRequestEntity.html#extractrequestentity) directive to create your route.  Once you have the entity stream you can simply dispatch each line of text to the `Actor`:

```
import akka.stream.scaladsl.Framing.delimiter
import akka.util.ByteString
import akka.actor.ActorRef
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives.{extractRequestEntity, onComplete}

val maxLineLength = 256

val streamSplitter = delimiter(ByteString("\n"), maxLineLength)

val actorRef : ActorRef = ??? //not specified in question

val route : Route = 
  extractRequestEntity { entity =>

    onComplete {
      entity
        .dataBytes
        .via(streamSplitter)
        .map(_.utf8String)
        .runForeach(line => actorRef ! line)
    } { _ =>
      complete("all lines sent to actor")
    }
  }
```

The question doesn't specify whether or not the response is dependent on the results of the Actor processing so the above example simply sends the lines to the Actor and then completes the request with a response containing a simple message.

The `route` can now [form the basis of a server](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/routing-dsl/index.html#minimal-example).

Comment: I'm giving it a try, but I get a compilation error on akka-http v10.0.9: value via is not a member of akka.http.scaladsl.model.RequestEntity.